# Content in navbar overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was toying around with the Bootstrap features when I encountered the problem of the navbar title lines overlapping each other when the window is resized.

Here's the code:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Title</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top unselectable">
            <h1 class="navbar-brand navbar-text">Very very very long title</h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn navbar-text">Basic</button>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

custom.css

```
body header
{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top
{
    background-color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 1);
}

.navbar-brand.navbar-text
{
    font-size: 55px;
    font-family: NAVBAR_TITLE;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    color: rgba(140, 0, 0, 1);
}

.navbar-brand.navbar-text:hover
{
    color: rgba(158, 47, 47, 1);
    cursor: default;
}
```

I've tried messing with line-height too but it's not exactly working as intended.

Comment: .navbar-brand has line-height of 20px thats why its overlapping

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is `.navbar-brand` has `height: 50px;` by default from bootstrap. Set it to auto in your custom css.

And of course set `line-height: 1;` to `.navbar-brand.navbar-text`.

```css
body header {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top {
  background-color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 1);
}

.navbar-brand.navbar-text {
  font-size: 55px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: NAVBAR_TITLE;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  color: rgba(140, 0, 0, 1);
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-brand.navbar-text:hover {
  color: rgba(158, 47, 47, 1);
  cursor: default;
}

.navbar-brand {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top unselectable">
    <h1 class="navbar-brand navbar-text">Very very very long title</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn navbar-text">Basic</button>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked great! Also, a tiny follow-up question.. is it good practice to have really long CSS files that seemingly have no structure? (basically just appending styles as the development of the site goes on). It seems kinda weird not to organize things even if its just CSS.

Comment: It&amp;#39;s ok while you develop it but I suggest refactoring your code before you go live. It will make it much more efficient and render faster to your users. Also. It will make reading your css and debugging it easier later on if it's well structured.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use below code :

.navbar-brand.navbar-text {line-height: 120%; }
.navbar-brand { height: auto !important; }
```

% : **line height** in percent of the current font size